# How to use custom function in apply method with H2O frame

Tags: python, h2o

I am trying to use the following code to apply function to each of the rows in a particular column of H2O frame, but getting error.

```
df["decision"] = df["resp_cd"].apply(lambda x:1 if x in ["00", 01", "11] else 0, axis=1)
```

[image]

Is there some other way to use user defined functions in H2O?

How should we use `apply` function in H2O? I expect it to be similar to `apply` function in Pandas but that doesn't seem to be true.

Comment: Also, I would really appreciate if people would just help me out with this, rather than down voting. I am using H2O for the first time so the questions might be a little basic, but I would love to learn and appreciate any help

Comment: You probably got downvoted for posting an image instead of text (just paste the text output and indent it with 4 spaces in order to format it properly). Make it easy to reproduce your problem for people trying to help you (perhaps posting the dataframe definition as well).

Comment: Maybe update your title to ask: how to use h20 apply method with an If else function (that way people can easily see from your question what issue you hit). Thanks!

Comment: Valid question. Should not be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally reasonable question. In your case you should actually use the .ifelse() method instead of the apply method,  H2O’s apply method is limited to a set of implemented math functions which can be used in a limited way in a lambda style function as well (note your error is just saying you are trying to use apply with an unimplimented method):

The following may solve your problem but you may need to play around with it:

(df[‘resp_cd’].isin([‘00’,’10’,’11’])).ifelse(1,0)

(Statement you want to test).ifelse(return if true,return if false).

You may need to change your column type to string or enum type with df[‘resp_cd’].ascharacter() or df[‘resp_cd’].asfactor() to get the code example above to work for you, but now you have a sense of how to apply a Boolean if else function to an H2OFrame.